# Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2

Tags: commerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Drupal Commerce ready for the real world?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/is-drupal-commerce-ready-for-the-real-world)

I am considering using [Kickstart 2](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) for a project.

Is Kickstart 2 stable ?

Does it allow for modifications or is it locked ?

Anyone experience with this. There doesn't seem to be many sites done using this.